# Scroll to position in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I have a `UIViewController` which contains several `UITableViews`. You can swipe through the `UITableViews` using a pagecontrol.

Now in another `UIViewController` you can navigate to a certain `UITableView`. I do it as following. In my `prepareForSegue` in the `viewController` I set a `pageNumber`. Then In my other `UIViewController` I am doing this.

```
-(void)jumpToPage:(NSNumber *)page{
    NSLog(@"jump to page");
    float offset=30;
    float height = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height;
    float width = 320 - (2*offset);
    int pagee = [page intValue] - 1;
    float x  = (320 * pagee) + offset;

    NSLog(@"X is %f",x);
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(x, 0, width , height) animated:NO];

}
```

This is causing that my `UIScrollView` is not scrollable anymore.
I don't know if it is important but this is what I'm doing in my `viewWillAppear`

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        // Set up the content size of the scroll view
        CGSize pagesScrollViewSize = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * self.pageStages.count, pagesScrollViewSize.height);
        [self loadVisiblePages];
        [self updateDay];

}
```

Can anybody help me with this??

**EDIT**

I've added this at the end of the jumpToPage method

```
   NSLog(@"content size is %d",320 * self.pageStages.count);
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 * self.pageStages.count, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
```

But this has still no effect.

Answer (score 7):

You can set frames according to ur needs and it will animate to next view with page control

```
 [scrollview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320,  80,320, 350) animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

The content size of the scroll view should be greater than the scroll view frame.If there is no content beyond the frame scroll view won't scroll.

Hence you can try increase the height of the content size (for vertical scrolls) and vice-versa for horizontal.

If You observe in your `viewWillAppear` the content height is the same as the scroll frame.I suspect this might affect the vertical scroll.

Hope this helps